# UserManagement.initVerificationMethod not working in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, authentication, mfa

The following function doesn't work for me and throws this error:

> System.NoDataFoundException: User does not have Salesforce Authenticator pairing

The goal is for me to create a custom login LWC for Salesforce Site and allows 3 different verification methods for the user. But I'm unable to get the authenticator app method to work.
Here is the code I tried and is failing in the commented line:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Auth.VerificationResult initVerification() {

    String id = UserManagement.initVerificationMethod(Auth.VerificationMethod.SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR); // this line fails and throws the error
    System.debug('*****id: '+id);

    Auth.VerificationResult res = System.UserManagement.verifyVerificationMethod(id, '', Auth.VerificationMethod.SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR);
    
    System.debug('*****res: '+res);
    System.debug('*****res.success: '+res.success);
    if(res.success == true){
            //redirect
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Note**: The site login user doesn't have the MFA permission set anymore, as I wanted to customize the MFA in 3 different ways - Authenticator App, SMS, Email.

Comment: You need to register the authenticator first via `initRegisterVerificationMethod` or other means such as admin console before you can use it by calling `initVerificationMethod`

Comment: initRegisterVerificationMethod only supports EMAIL and SMS as per this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm#apex_System_UserManagement_initRegisterVerificationMethod. But I did try registerVerificationMethod() but that gave me another error: "insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary"

Comment: Yes. You will have to try a combination of `initRegisterVerificationMethod` and/or `registerVerificationMethod`. You'll need to make sure that the user you're executing as has enough privileges to make these calls.

Comment: Can you please tell me what privileges I need to assign the user in the profile/permission set level to perform this operation?